# JQuery background-position animation infinitely

Tags: jquery, background-position

So what I have is a big image that I'm trying to animate continuously while someone is on the page

What I do now is:

```
$('.photobanner').animate({ 
    backgroundPosition:"(-10000px 0px)" 
}, 80000, 'linear');
```

and this works .. but it seems it comes to an end and stops .. can I do the same animation infinitely ??

NOW IT WORKS ----

```
var counter=0;
function moveBG(y)
{
    counter=counter-1000;
    $('.photobanner').animate({ backgroundPosition:"("+counter+"px 0px)" }, 8000, 'linear',moveBG);
}
```

I defined a counter which will be incremented to infinity and used the this function.

Comment: If the end and the beginning of the image are identical, you can just reset the image and restart the animation at the end of the animate function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always do something like this:

```
function moveBG()
{
    $('.photobanner').css({ backgroundPosition:"(0px 0px)"});
    $('.photobanner').animate({ backgroundPosition:"(-1000px 0px)" }, 8000, 'linear',moveBG);
}
```

So that the callback of the function redoes the function. It would have to be a seemless image though.

Comment: well its right although I had to edit something
(you can take a look up ;) )